# Ranking in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ranking

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select
    restaurant_id,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY restaurant_id order by churn desc) as rank_churn,
    churn,
    orders,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY restaurant_id order by orders desc) as rank_orders

from data
```

I would expect that this ranking function will order my data and provide a column that has 1,2,3,4 according to the values of the column.
However the outcome is always 1 in the ranking.

```
restaurant_id rank_churn    churn  orders   rank_orders
2217             1             75   182          1
2249             1             398  896          1
2526             1             11   56           1
2596             1             89   139          1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is only one row for each restaurant_id - of course the rank for that single row is always 1. You probably need to remove the `partition by` part.

Comment: I posted and then I just figured out :) Yes, rank() over (order by orders) works!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think people is ashamed to post answers to very simple problems. This way there are now plenty of questions answered only in the comments.